# Eclipse with preinstalled plugins

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi i was using Easy Eclipse J2EE distribution, as most of the plugins which usually  a J2EE developer will need is already pre-installed( Sub-eclipse few others) in it. recently i have started facing problems with Easy eclipse as it has only 32 bit version which do work on 64 bit machines but we can not set xmX values greater then 2GB , as my project size has been increased considerably, this distribution oftenly hangs / goes unresponsive, So I am looking for some free alternative if its there?
Fetching 64 bit J2ee eclipse and installing subeclipse/subverse with Correct Java HL and Connecter seems a bit of uphill task on 64 bit systems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Yoxos](http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/), which is a Web Tool for configurating the Eclipse PLatform with as many additional features, as you want.
You do not have to add features manually by copying them into any directory.

Answer (score -1):

I think may be instead of easy eclipse then, you should grab Eclipse for Java EE developers 64 bit from the eclipse site and install rest of the plugins yourself which are not present which should'nt be very hard.